# OLE DB provider for Teradata 15.10.04?

Tags: oledb, teradata

I'm setting up a brand new system and decided to install TTU 15.10.04 (my old machine had TTU 14).  When I run my apps, I get this error:

`The 'TDOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

I used to get this error on earlier versions, but all I had to do was make sure my app was running in 32-bit mode.  After checking everything multiple times and not being able to isolate the problem, I searched for the OLE DB installation folder on my new machine, but have not been able to find it.  So I checked my old machine and found that it was installed here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\Client\14.00\OLE DB Provider for Teradata`

I have no such equivalent folder on my new machine.  The only thing I have is OLE DB Access Module, but I am sure that's not it.  I have concluded that I do not have the OLE DB provider installed at all and cannot seem to find out where to get it.  It's as if it has disappeared.  Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can download the teradata oledb provider for ttu15 [HERE](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/ole-db-provider)
Hope this helps

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that, but that's version 15.00 and I have 15.10.04.  When I try to install, it tells me it's not compatible with the shared ICU libraries I have installed.  I'll need OLD DB provider for 15.10.04.  Also updated my answer to mention 15.10.04

Comment: Did you install the ODBC drivers before trying to run the OLE DB install? That was part of the install instructions for ole db. I know you already installed TTU, but you might just need to update the ODBC drivers ICU libraries